# Planes do not Appear in the 3D View

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, dimensions, outliner

*Plane object selected but not visible:*

[image]

For some reason, when I try to add a *Plane* mesh, it doesn't appear in the 3D Viewport no matter how much I scale it. It's as if it's invisible. I even tried changing the dimensions but they reset to 0. What have I done? How do I fix this? Note that it's only the plane mesh that's acting up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

You cannot scale it because of the *Zero-product Property*. This is a mathematical theorem that [Hotmath](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/zero-product-property.html) defines by saying:

> The Zero Product Property simply states that if a*b=0, then either a=0 or  b=0 (or both). A product of factors is zero if and only if one or more of the factors is zero.

This relates to your issue because you are trying to multiply the dimensions (let the *Object Dimensions* be represented by **a**) -- set at 0 -- by a non-zero value (let that random, non-zero value be **b**). As Blender follows the various laws of mathematics, the dimensions will always return to zero.

### Solution

When first you add a *Plane* object and before you click on **anything** else, you should be presented with a number of settings in the *Toolshelf* on the left side of the *3D Viewport*. Make sure the *Radius:* value is set to a non-zero value. If it is set to zero, it will likely spawn at zero each time you try.

*Bad:*

[image]

*Good:*

[image]